# How to use a file pointer in a called function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I wrote some code as a school exercise.
We need to use structs and functions for this exercise.
I want to read some date out a file with one function and save this data to a struct. Next i have another function to do an easy calculation on this data. 
I initialize my filepointer in the main function with fopen, the problem is i want to use the same pointer in a function called by the main.
My program compiles when i declare my FILE *fp outside the main function but it crashes while running. 
Does anyone can help me with this? Thank you all.
Here is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
    int dag;
    int maand;
    int jaar;
}geboortedag;

typedef struct 
{
    char name[BUFSIZ];
    geboortedag dag;
}persoon;

void readperson(persoon *);
geboortedag calculate(p);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    persoon a;
    persoon *p;
    p = &a;
    geboortedag leeftijd;

    if (argc != 5)
    {
        printf("Het aantal argumenten die ingegeven is niet correct\n");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (argc == 5)
    {
        if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("De file kon niet worden geopend\n");
            getchar();
            exit(2);
        }
    }

    readperson(p);
    leeftijd = calculate(p);
    printf("De leeftijd is %d %d %d", leeftijd.dag, leeftijd.maand,   leeftijd.jaar);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Het bestand is correct afegsloten");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void readperson(persoon *x)
{
    char a[BUFSIZ];
    fgets(a, BUFSIZ, fp);
    strcpy(x->name, a);
    fscanf("%d%d%d", x->dag.dag, x->dag.maand, x->dag.jaar);
}

geboortedag calculate(persoon *x)
{
    geboortedag tijd;
    int a, b, c;
    a = atoi(x->dag.dag);
    b = atoi(x->dag.maand);
    c = atoi(x->dag.jaar);
    tijd.dag = x->dag.dag - a;
    tijd.maand = x->dag.maand;
    tijd.jaar = x->dag.jaar;
    return tijd;
}
```

EDIT:
So i tried what was suggested here. I'm still getting an error about the filepointer that might not be initialized...

Error   C4703   potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'fp' used

This is the updated code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
    int dag;
    int maand;
    int jaar;
}geboortedag;

typedef struct
{
    char name[BUFSIZ];
    geboortedag dag;
}persoon;

void readperson(FILE* fp, persoon *p);
geboortedag calculate(persoon *p);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    persoon a;
    persoon *p;
    p = &a;
    geboortedag leeftijd;

    if (argc != 5)
    {
        printf("Het aantal argumenten die ingegeven is niet correct\n");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (argc == 5)
    {
        if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("De file kon niet worden geopend\n");
            getchar();
            exit(2);
        }
    }

    readperson(fp, p);
    leeftijd = calculate(p);
    printf("De leeftijd is %d %d %d", leeftijd.dag, leeftijd.maand, leeftijd.jaar);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Het bestand is correct afegsloten");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void readperson(FILE* fp, persoon *x)
{
    char a[BUFSIZ];
    fgets(a, BUFSIZ, fp);
    strcpy(x->name, a);
    fscanf(fp, "%d%d%d", &x->dag.dag, &x->dag.maand, &x->dag.jaar);
}

geboortedag calculate(persoon *x)
{
    geboortedag tijd = { 0, 0, 0 };
    /*int a, b, c;
    a = atoi(x->dag.dag);
    b = atoi(x->dag.maand);
    c = atoi(x->dag.jaar);
    tijd.dag = x->dag.dag - a;
    tijd.maand = x->dag.maand;
    tijd.jaar = x->dag.jaar;*/
    return tijd;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create the separate `p` variable, just passing `&a` will do.

Comment: Add some ampersands here: `fscanf("%d%d%d",  &x->dag.dag, &x->dag.maand, &x->dag.jaar);`   And, you dont need the atoi(), these variables **are** ints: `a = atoi(x->dag.dag);`

Comment: @wildplasser argv returns strings. so i have to convert them into integers?

Comment: `printf("Het aantal argumenten die ingegeven is niet correct\n");` And please correct your Dutch... (**het** aantal, **dat**, or **die** ingegeven **zijn**) . And: `x->dag.dag` is not `argv[xxx]`

Comment: @wildplasser this is a code related issue and has nothing to do with my grammar. Apart from me and people who are able to read Dutch, nobody cares about it. But thank you for the input

Comment: Also, the message is non-informative. Instead, it should say how many arguments were expected, and how many were encountered. Same for: `printf("De file kon niet worden geopend\n");` : **which** file? (and: diagnostic output should go to stderr)

Comment: I get lots of warnings when I compile this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite strange that it crashes when you declare fp globally but since you gave no more details, let's leave it.

Simply pass the file pointer to every procedure that needs it. So, their protos change into

```
void readperson(FILE *, persoon *);
```

and they are called as

```
readperson(fp, p);
```

from the main.

Comment: so why is this strange? When i run the program with cmd and give in al my arguments. cmd closes and i receive windows message telling the program stopped working. What could be the reason to this?

Comment: Well, not exactly strange, let's say there were more code modifications than simply moving the pointer outside of main. BTW, how do you run it, as a command issued in console?

Comment: I use cmd and go the the directory where my .exe is. Then I type in the program name and the necessary arguments to go with it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to simply pass the file pointer to the `read` function:

```
void readperson(FILE *fp, persoon *x);
```

Then in `main`:

```
readperson(fp, p);
```

Comment: this returns in error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'fp' used

Comment: @michielreyntjens C4703 is a warning, not an error. I don't know what else you changed in your code, so it's hard to tell, but...

Comment: C4703 is an error. i't stopped compiling caused to this error. I just did what you suggested, pass the filepointer to the function. the C4703 says my filepointer is probably not initialized. which it is clearly...

Comment: @michielreyntjens No, it's not an error. It's a warning; perhaps your IDE is configured to treat warnings as errors. And your code has other errors preventing the build anyway. [Here it is compiling with no warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09fb932d8045fa0b).

Comment: The code you sen't me still gives an error on line 64. where you put the braces behind tijd. It asks for a semicolon. When i put the code back you commented out i juste have the same errors?

Comment: @michielreyntjens yeah, but that's another function. The part you were asking about is done correctly.

Comment: What is the reason you added the brackers {} to the instance of tijd "geboortedag tijd {};"? i understand what you did but when i try to solve the calculate function it still gives the error about the file pointer?